# Sync changes to and fro converted physical machine VM

Tags: vmware-converter

Is there a way to sync changes made in the VM back to the physical machine? The VM was converted through VMWare's converter. I would like to sometimes sync to and fro changes made on the VM and on the physical machine, is there a way to do so in VMware?

Comment: That's not how P2V conversion works.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You don't want conversion, you want... I don't quite know, but it's not P2V conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at products like PlateSpin (now owned by Novell).

Comment: A horrible piece of software, but it does indeed do this.